# Adding the address command-line argument to the Java Development Server causes error when uploading blobs

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, blobstore, gae-eclipse-plugin

I have a Google App Engine (GAE) application running on Java with Eclipse. I wish to access the development server from other computers on the same LAN, so
I added the `--address=0.0.0.0` (or `-a 0.0.0.0`) command-line argument when running it locally on Eclipse.

After adding this argument, however, I can no longer upload datastore entities that contain a blob. When I try to upload a blob using the `BlobstoreService.createUploadUrl()` method I get `Error 401` on my browser. The upload works fine when I don't add the address argument to the server.

This is how my HTML form looks like in the JSP file where I perform the upload:

```
<form method="post" id="form1" name="form1"
action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/servletName") %>"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**Extra note:**

Before adding the address argument, the HTML source displayed by the browser looked like this in the `createUploadUrl` portion:

```
action="http://localhost:8888/_ah/upload/agpzbWFzcnYtcG9zciILEhVfX0Jsb2JVcGxvYWRTZXNzaW9uX18YgICAgICA6AkM"
```

After adding that argument, the code displayed by the browser looked like this:

```
action="http://Lenovo-PC:8888/_ah/upload/agpzbWFzcnYtcG9zciILEhVfX0Jsb2JVcGxvYWRTZXNzaW9uX18YgICAgICA6AkM"
```

(it used the hostname of my computer instead of the *localhost* keyword)

Comment: **Extra note:** The same thing occurs when trying to serve (download) images or blobs from the server. I use the `ImagesService.getServingUrl()` method, which returns a URL like this `http://0.0.0.0:8888/_ah/img/THS2pVDYwDJR-KyK5ih4Dg`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be your IP configuration or host name resolution.  What OS are you running?  The Lenovo-PC name suggests Windows.  The 0.0.0.0 address in the download URL might be unworkable too.  Can you ping 0.0.0.0?  If you have a stable IP address, replace the 0.0.0.0 with that.

Comment: Yes, I am running it on Windows 8. I used 0.0.0.0 (I'm thinking it's like a subnet mask) to allow any IP address to connect to the development server. Assigning a fixed IP like 192.168.1.2 to the address argument does fix the problem, but it doesn't allow other IPs to connect to the server.

Comment: If things now work locally but not remotely the next problem is most likely network configuration.  Verify that the computers can ping each other.  Windows 8 may need a firewall rule to allow port 8888 to receive incoming TCP connections.